# Deployed xgboost model fail with an error when calling prediction function

Tags: python, amazon-s3, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Amazon SageMaker (SageMaker: 2.24.1) to build and deploy a model on the classical "orders_with_predicted_value.csv" dataset. Everything works fine with the training, and the model deploys well, but when I call the prediction method on the test data I get the following error:

> AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Accept'",
> 'occurred at index 0')

I opened the prediction function of SageMaker trying to solve this issue but to no effect.

Here's my code:
[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you paste a text version of your code into the question, with proper code formatting? Images of code are generally more difficult for users to interact with.

Comment: Hello bbnumber2, thank you for your suggestions, i approuve it. i will try to add a text version of my code